# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in maven on LORA

Tags: java, maven

(I know that this questions has already been asked before but I'm not able to solve this problem with those answers)
I'm pretty new to java and I'm trying to write some code to acces and use data from https://console.thethingsnetwork.org/ when I do `mvn -X -f "C:\xampp\perl\vendor\lib\Apache\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\data-mqtt\pom.xml" clean compile exec:java`
 I get this. (debug/error from terminal)

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:466)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:566)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:499)
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:270)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:844) [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 5.844 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2018-06-18T10:47:08+02:00 [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on
>   project data-mqtt: An exception occured while executing the Java
>   class. App -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java
>   (default-cli) on project data-mqtt: An exception occured while
>   executing the Java class. App
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
>   (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356) Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured
>   while executing the Java class. App
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute (ExecJavaMojo.java:339)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
>   (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:466)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:566)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:499)
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:270)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:844)

this is my App.java so far

```
 `
public class App {
public static Client client;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String region = "eu";
    String appId = "stuf1";
    String accessKey = "stuf2";

   try {
        client = new Client(region, appId, accessKey);
    } catch (URISyntaxException var5) {
        System.out.println(var5);
    }
    client.onError((_error) -> {
        System.out.println("error: " + _error.getMessage());
    });
    client.onConnected((_client) -> {
        System.out.println("connected !");
    });
}}
```

and my pom.xml

```
    <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>Codehaus Mojo</id>
      <name>Codehaus Mojo</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/codehaus- 
      snapshots/</url>
      </repository>
  </repositories>
    <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
            <mainClass>App</mainClass>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>run-App.java</id>
              <phase>integration-test</phase>
              <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

          <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>

          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <staleMillis>1</staleMillis>
            <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.21.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

if anyone could help me that would be appreciated if you need any more details please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didn't have the propper path changed 
`<mainClass>App</mainClass>` to `<mainClass>org.thethingsnetwork.samples.mqtt.App</mainClass>`